# how to populate 3 list python from text file

Tags: python, list

I have a text file that has an accnumber, PIN number,balance for many users. 
I want to read the text file and split its data into 3 different lists but don't know how. (I'm creating a bank management system for school assessment.)

Example text file:

```
98768
8077.00
Jim McIntyre
58697
23233.99
Michael Murphy
35318
4545.12
Abigail Buckley
20454
23233.45
Marie Delaney
```

Comment: Great bank management system! What is your question?

Comment: I want to read the text file and split its data into 3 different lists

Answer (score 0):

Read the file in and split the data into lists.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as fp:
    data = fp.read().split('\n')

acc_numbers = list(map(int, data[::3]))
pin_numbers = list(map(float, data[1::3]))
balances = data[2::3]

print(acc_numbers, pin_numbers, balances)

# [98768, 58697, 35318, 20454] 
# [8077.0, 23233.99, 4545.12, 23233.45] 
# ['Jim McIntyre', 'Michael Murphy', 'Abigail Buckley', 'Marie Delaney']
```